# Facebook's send and like button isn't working together

Tags: facebook, wordpress, plugins, facebook-like, xfbml

I'm a Wordpress [plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/facebook-send-like-button/) developer. I'm working with Facebook's *like* and *send* buttons.

I'm using this XFBML code :

```
<div id="fb-root"></div><script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=119608038121612&amp;xfbml=1"></script><fb:like href="http://jsfiddle.net" send="true" width="450" show_faces="true" font=""></fb:like>
```

There is **send=true** parameter but still showing only *like* button. You can check live example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/teknoblogo/zEfWT/). I got this code from [Official Facebook Developer page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/). Also this code isn't working on Facebook's site, too.

So, do you have any idea ? How can we solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I just checked but it seems to work fine?
When i run your piece of code i see a 'like' and 'send' button and they both work.

[image: Screenshot Here]